# How to change Class, when I use several checkbox?

Tags: jquery

I receive from Spring some table in this table I have two checkbox. I need to do when first checkbox is checked, I change Class to OneClass, when second checkbox is checked, I change Class to TwoClass, when two checkbox checked together, I change Class to ThreeClass.

[http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/Magnit/cUxmG/142/)

I wrote some code, this code is working if I use one checkbox, but I don't understand how to do this code for two checkbox as I need as I describe above

```
  $(".ifChange input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
            $(this).closest("tr").addClass("oneClass");
   });
  $(".ifChange input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){

     if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).closest("tr").addClass("oneClass");
    } else {
        $(this).closest("tr").removeClass("oneClass");
    }          
   });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".ifChange input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
  orderClasses($(this));
}).change();

function orderClasses($el) {
  var tr = $el.closest("tr"),
    receive = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name='receiveOrder']"),
    send = tr.find("input[type='checkbox'][name='sentOrderToCustomer']");

  tr.removeClass("oneClass twoClass threeClass");

  if (receive.is(":checked")) {
    if (send.is(":checked")) {
      tr.addClass("threeClass");
    } else {
      tr.addClass("oneClass");
    }
  } else if (send.is(":checked")) {
    tr.addClass("twoClass");
  }
}
```

```css
table.ifChange tr.oneClass {
  background-color: #a39fa1;
}

table.ifChange tr.twoClass {
  background-color: #5da300;
}

table.ifChange tr.threeClass {
  background-color: #a34800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" class="ifChange" style="margin-top: 20px">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <span>Name One</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span>phone One</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span id="orderDate">oderDate</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="receive">
        <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" />
        <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="sent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" />
        <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <span>Name Two</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span>phone Two</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span id="orderDate">oderDate Two</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="receive">
        <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" />
        <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="sent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" checked="checked" />
        <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <span>Name Three</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span>phone Three</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span id="orderDate">oderDate three</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="receive">
        <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" checked="checked" />
        <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="sent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" />
        <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <span>Name four</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span>phone four</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <span id="orderDate">oderDate four</span>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="receive">
        <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" checked="checked" />
        <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
      <div class="sent">
        <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" checked="checked" />
        <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use length attribute for check if all checkbox is checked. And after check each checkbox. I have make a function you can call. Try bellow

```js
$(".ifChange input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
      checkClass($(this))
});
 
 $(".ifChange input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
      checkClass($(this))
});

function checkClass(_self){
    _self.closest("tr").removeClass();
    checkboxLen = _self.closest("tr").find("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
    if(checkboxLen == 2){
      _self.closest("tr").addClass("threeClass");
    }else if(_self.closest("tr").find(".receiveOrder").is(":checked")){
     _self.closest("tr").addClass("oneClass");
    }else if(_self.closest("tr").find(".sentOrderToCustomer").is(":checked")){
     _self.closest("tr").addClass("twoClass");
    }  
}
```

```css
table.ifChange tr.oneClass {
    background-color: #a39fa1;
}
table.ifChange tr.twoClass {
    background-color: #5da300;
}
table.ifChange tr.threeClass {
  background-color: #a34800;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <table border="1" class="ifChange" style="margin-top: 20px">
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span>Name One</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span>phone One</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span id="orderDate">oderDate</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="receive">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder"/>
                <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="sent">
                <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer"/>
                <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span>Name Two</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span>phone Two</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span id="orderDate">oderDate Two</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="receive">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder"/>
                <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="sent">
                <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" checked="checked"/>
                <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span>Name Three</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span>phone Three</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span id="orderDate">oderDate three</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="receive">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" checked="checked"/>
                <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="sent">
                <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer"/>
                <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td align="center">
                <span>Name four</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span>phone four</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <span id="orderDate">oderDate four</span>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="receive">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="receiveOrder" name="receiveOrder" checked="checked"/>
                <br/><span>  Order on warehouse</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td align="center">
                <div class="sent">
                <input type="checkbox" class="sentOrderToCustomer" name="sentOrderToCustomer" checked="checked"/>
                <br/><span>  Order sent</span>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
```